# What is the difference between Selenium and Mozrepl?

Tags: perl, firefox, selenium

From what I can gather, mozrepl uses WWW::Mechanize::Firefox to automate firefox. 
ie. you create scripts and hit interpreted commands that shoot to the firefox browser as output.

Selenium on the other hand lets you record actions in the browser, and you can output the actions as scripts in various languages.

So essentially, mozrepl takes scripts (fragments) as input and outputs as browser actions. Selenium takes browser actions and outputs them as a script.

Or can they both perform these function? Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selenium generated scripts can then be run, so it does perform both functions.

You have it backwards; WWW::Mechanize::Firefox uses mozrepl, not the other way around.

Selenium is implemented in javascript on the browser and supports multiple browsers; it is usually used for testing.

WWW::Mechanize::Firefox, on the other hand, is usually used for scraping or to perform some action needing a browser, not testing.

Comment: Thanks, so just to clarify: using Mechanize::Firefox (which uses mozrepl) cannot be used to automatically create scripts via browser actioins, unlike selenium.

Comment: Seleniuym 1 uses JavaScript injection, Selenium 2 uses WebDriver, a different mechanism altogether.

Answer (score 2):

You have misunderstood [`MozRepl`](https://github.com/bard/mozrepl/wiki) and [`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox)
. `Mozrepl` is an extension to Firefox that provides a telnet interface (by default on port 4242) that offers direct access to the internal functions of Firefox's [Gecko engine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Gecko) including the Document Object Model of each window.

This interface can be used directly at a console or driven by software such as the Perl `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` module, which presents an interface similar to the `WWW::Mechanize` module. There is also a [`MozRepl`](https://metacpan.org/module/MozRepl) Perl module that connects to the extension in the same way but provides a different API.

Comment: Ok, thanks for explaining that. I am assuming I am correct that using firefox mechanize is a way to use firefox with code, but selenium creates the code from user  actions...